# Is there a better way to do Business Logic job scheduling than SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I was listening to a recent Brent Ozar Office hours and someone asked about using SQL Server Agent or Windows Task scheduler to schedule business logic jobs. Ozar mentioned that neither of those is satisfactory for enterprise workloads. He said that an application server ought to be used to handle scheduling business logic.

I'm just curious what the community thinks about SQL Server Agent vs using an app server.

I work at a company that uses many third party tools; we don't have our own app. So, I don't have developers on hand to create a scheduling tool. Many of the 3rd party apps we use don't have a means to interface their scheduling utility with other services, so I typically use either SQL Server Agent or Windows Scheduler.

Just curious what you all think.

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective question. It all depends on workload, on hardware you have, on availability of operators to control the scheduling... too many variables to give one definitive answer.

The most objective solution I can give: do what you can. If the current solution is not enough - look for another one. Just remember, that there is no perfect, all encompassing solutions. And do not expect that the approach which works for your expert (even specially hired to solve your problem), will work for you.

---

In my personal experience, the  external scheduler gives you more flexibility. The SSA is just too SQL Server centric. If you have only SQL Server, then SSA is fine. But if you have at least some other DBMS and need to transfer data - or your system does not end with database... SSA is just not enough.

And, of course, the most effective and "just what you need" solution would be a homebrew scheduler. You can tweak it exactly as you need, it can handle all workload, it is very convenient to use. The only downside - it requires a person who would write that scheduler.